# How do I change the UI in MediaWiki v1.16.4?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm probably overlooking something obvious, but I cannot seem to find any information about changing from the default UI in MediaWiki.  I want to use the newest 1st party UI (seen on http://en.wikipedia.org/ and other non-WikiMedia web sites like http://minecraftwiki.net/). How can I accomplish this?

My site, although intranet only, uses the default UI which is very similar to this modified one:  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about configuring MediaWiki skins here: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skin_configuration

This new skin in WikiPedia is called "Vector."

Comment: That was an incredibly simple fix. Thanks a bunch.